# How to periodically use StartScan() in WifiManager so that I can catch a WIFI spot immediately after it is available?

Tags: android, wifi, periodic-task

I would like to be able to detect whether there is a WIFI spot in the vicinity. I use `WifiManager.startScan()` method, I can make SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION intent fire, and I can obtain the Wifi spot results though `WifiManager.getScanResults()`, but this happens only once. For example there are wifi spots named A,B,C in the vicinity. I call `WifiManager.startScan()` and I find wifi spots A,B,C. However, after this point if another wifi spot named D appears in the vicinity, I cannot see it. How can I catch wifi spot D in this case? I related code in the following. I would appreciate your help.

```
    tManager.startScan();
if (WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            Log.i("WiFiDirectBrdcastRcvr", "FOUND WIFI SPOT");
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = tManager.getScanResults();
            wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
            Log.i("WiFiDirectBrdcastRcvr", "Device found " + wifiScanList.size()+" WIFI spots");
            for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
                wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
                Log.i("WiFiDirectBrdcastRcvr", "Spot" + i + " is: " + wifis[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your start scan code in handler

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() 
{ 
   @Override public void handleMessage(Message message) 
   { 

   } 
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler h=new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        WifiManager.startScan();  
    }
},20000);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.